# Insert a conditional column in R

Tags: r, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a client dataset with three columns. The first one is my client id, the second is a date when the purchase was made and the third is a date when I enter in contact with them.

I would like to know if my contact is efective. So, I would like to insert a column with a 1 if the client returns after contact and zero if he returns with no contact.

So, 1 -> if the customer returned and the new purchase date is bigger than the last contacts dates.

0 -> No return, contact date is NA or the new purchase date is less than past contact date.

I would like to insert a new column, to model it. The dataset is:

```
client <- c("A","B","C","D","E","G","C","B","D","J","A","E","E","A","C")
purchase <- as.Date(c("2017-04-02","2017-04-07","2017-04-10", "2017-04-
13","2017-04-17","2017-04-18","2017-04-20","2017-04-22","2017-04-25","2017-
04-27","2017-04-30","2017-05-10","2017-05-12","2017-05-15","2017-05-20"))
contact <- as.Date(c("2017-05-05",NA,"2017-04-11", "2017-04-14",NA,"2017-04-
20","2017-04-21",NA,"2017-04-30",NA,"2017-05-30",NA,NA,"2017-05-15",NA))
data <- data.frame(client, purchase, contact)
```

The output is:

```
data$output <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

And I've tried this:

```
 data$return <- with(data, ave(as.character(client), as.character(client), 
 sum(client == client, purchase > contact)))
```

Thank you

Comment: ```dplyr::mutate``` with an ```if_else``` should do what you want.